# Jclouds does not return all private ip address of aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, jclouds, network-interface

I have made use of apache jclouds library to fetch ec2 instance details. I have attached 2 network interfaces on a single ec2 instance to provide it 2 IPs.

[image]

But from the following code of jclouds, I see only one IP (of primary interface [eth0]) getting retrieved.

```
ComputeService cs = computeContext.getComputeService();
for (ComputeMetadata cm : cs.listNodes()){
        NodeMetadata nm = (NodeMetadata) cm;
        System.out.println(nm);
    }
```

In the output I can see only one IP address:

> privateAddresses=[172.26.119.234]

Is someone else facing the same problem? If anyone has a solution for this, I will be really thankful to know.

Answer (score 1):

jclouds reads the private ip address from the [Instance#privateIpAddress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Instance.html) field, and it looks like AWS only populates there the first ip address. Instead, jclouds should retrieve all NICs assotiaced with the instance and get the private addresses from there. Mind opening an issue in the [jclouds JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JCLOUDS)?

Comment: I have raised an issue for the same [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1426)